# how to change positive value to negative

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Input parameter

```
@SMSSessionTimeout AS INT
```

Suppose `@SMSSessionTimeout = 300`

While using inside `begin...end`, I want to make it negative value.
Like `@SMSSessionTimeout = -300`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38):

Multiply it by -1

```
SELECT @SMSSessionTimeout = @SMSSessionTimeout * -1;
```

Comment: I do love the multiply by -1 trick though.  Use of minus also very handy for dates.  e.g. DATEADD(day,-1, getdate())

Comment: IS there a more opposite of 'ABSOLUTE' way to do it....what if you have to run a sp again and then will turn the - back to a +.....

Comment: @JeffOrris  Refer Anthony Faull answer for the absolute way

Comment: Faull's answer is also sensitive to revert negative back to positive. But you could check beforehand if the value is still positive before converting.

Answer (score 13):

Prefix the value with a minus sign.

```
SET @SMSSessionTimeout = -@SMSSessionTimeout
```

Comment: I know it's virtually the same thing as yours, but i use SET @SMSSessionTimeout = (0 - @SMSSessionTimeout);  for readability :)

Comment: This is the solution presented in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/unary-operators-negative?view=sql-server-2017#b-changing-a-variable-to-a-negative-value

Comment: Using just `-` by itself (e.g. `SELECT -col AS NegCol FROM myTable`) gives me SR0014 in SSDT in VS2019, apparently it thinks the data-type of the column is `Unknown` - weird.

Answer (score 4):

I think the logic below will work perfectly to convert positive numbers into negative.

```
IF(@SMSSessionTimeout > 0)
   SET @SMSSessionTimeout = 0 - @SMSSessionTimeout
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to ensure that a negative value will be produced, you could use:

```
SET @SMSSessionTimeout = -ABS(@SMSSessionTimeout);
```

More about ABS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple bit flip cut it?

```
    SELECT @SMSSessionTimeout & x80000000;
```

A bit awkward, but why go through a full add operation when you only want to change the sign?